# uploading multiple .txt files to a server via FTP combines them to a single file on server

Tags: ftp, text-files

When I upload multiple .txt files to the server via FTP, they automatically combine to a single file with no extension and given a name same as that of its parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

What's your question? if FTP Server was wrote by yourself, I think It's very easy. cache all files into memory[your files are small], create another thread to combine.